# JPA (Hibernate-backed) Maker-Checker Multi-Level Inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

The strategy I'm taking to implementing a maker-checker scenario is through using multiple tables. Currently, I'm using Hibernate 4.2 (annotations). The following scenario is what I would like to achieve. However, I'm having problems with the multi-level inheritance.

The basic idea is that there are two tables (`pending` and `approved`). When an `add()` occurs, the entry is inserted into the `pending` table. When that entry is approved, it is removed from the `pending` table and inserted into the `approved` table.

```
Policy (the policy)
|
+ -- Pending (maker information)
     |
     + -- Approved (checker information)
```

So, class `Policy` is the class that defines the necessary fields for a policy. To keep this post shorter, the fields are not be shown.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS) // problem
public abstract class Policy { ... }
```

The `Pending` class is for the newly-added `Policy` that is awaiting approval and it has information on the maker/adder.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pending")
public class Pending extends Policy {
    @Column(name = "adder", ...)
    private String adder;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "time_added", ...)
    private Date timeAdded;
}
```

The `Approved` class is for approved entities and it contains additional information on the approver in addition to the information from the `Pending` class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "approved")
public class Approved extends Pending {
    @Column(name = "approver", ...)
    private String approver;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "time_approved", ...)
    private Date timeApproved;
}
```

My first thought was to try `TABLE_PER_CLASS`. However, it resulted in the following runtime error: `org.hibernate.MappingException: Cannot use identity column key generation with <union-subclass> mapping for: ...`. The solution for this is to modify the base class `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` to `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)`. However, modifying that class is beyond my scope as it is shared across multiple projects.

Just for the heck of it, I tried the other two strategies. Obviously, `SINGLE_TABLE` resulted in one table, with an extra column `DTYPE`. Not what we wanted. `JOINED` resulted in two tables, but the `approved` table has a foreign key to the `pending` table. Since we wanted to remove an entry from the `pending` table and move it to the `approved` table, this would not work for us.

Currently, my solution is to as follows, which is basically copy and paste the code from the `Pending` class into the `Approved` class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "approved")
public class Approved extends Policy {
    @Column(name = "adder", ...)
    private String adder;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "time_added", ...)
    private Date timeAdded;
    @Column(name = "approver", ...)
    private String approver;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "time_approved", ...)
    private Date timeApproved;
}
```

This solution seems counter-intuitive as it duplicates code. Is there a solution that does not require code duplication and keeps the maker-checker process that way it currently works?

Comment: This hierarchy does not seem to suffice the 'Is-a' rule. An **approved** something is no longer **pending**. It is probably rather a naming issue. I would create unrelated `Creation` and  `Approval` classes with a 1-1 relationship to the entity.

Comment: What does 'none of them worked as described` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After experimenting with the suggested approach by @kostja, I arrived at the following solution.

The maker class encapsulates information pertaining to the maker, which is also an `@Embeddable` class.

```
@Embedabble
public class Maker {
    @Column(name="maker_id", ...)
    private String makerId;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="time_added", ...)
    private Date timeAdded;
}
```

Similarly, the checker class also encapsulates information pertaining to the checker, which is also an `@Embeddable` class.

```
@Embedabble
public class Checker {
    @Column(name="checker_id", ...)
    private String makerId;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="time_approved", ...)
    private Date timeApproved;
}
```

The payload is an `@Embeddable` class. By making the payload an `@Embeddable` class, the `Maker` and `Checker` can be reused for multiple payloads.

```
@Embeddable
public class Payload { ... }
```

For example, given two different payloads that requires maker/checker. One of the payload requires 2 checker.

```
@Embeddable
public class PayloadA { ... }
@Embeddable
public class PayloadB { ... }
```

Then we define the following two tables for `PayloadA`.

```
@Entity
@Table("a_pending")
public class PendingA {
    @Embedded
    private PayloadA payload;
    @Embedded
    private Maker maker;
}

@Entity
@Table("a_approved")
public class ApprovedA {
    @Embedded
    private PayloadA payload;
    @Embedded
    private Maker maker;
    @Embedded
    private Checker checker;
}
```

Similarly, for `PayloadB` define two tables. And `PayloadB` requires two checkers.

```
@Entity
@Table("b_pending")
public class PendingB {
    @Embedded
    private PayloadB payload;
    @Embedded
    private Maker maker;
}

@Entity
@Table("b_approved")
public class ApprovedB {
    @Embedded
    private PayloadB payload;
    @Embedded
    private Maker maker;
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides(value = {
       @AttributeOverride(name="checkerId",column="checker1_id"),
       @AttributeOverride(name="timeApproved",column="checker1_time_approved"),
    })
    private Checker checker1;
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverrides(value = {
       @AttributeOverride(name="checkerId",column="checker2_id"),
       @AttributeOverride(name="timeApproved",column="checker2_time_approved"),
    })
    private Checker checker2;
}
```

I hope this solution should be general and flexible enough.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a different approach for this. I assume `Policy` is your entity - the one carrying the real payload. You would like to add some metadata to it. Inheritance does not look as a good fit for this to me. A `Pending` is not an `Policy` and an `Approved` is not a `Pending`.

Instead of inheritance, I would model the metadata as separate, unrelated entities and create 1-1 relationships to the payload entity. Or many-to-one, if you need multiple approvals.

This way, you have a better decoupled data model and a more normalized DB structure. This gives you more flexibility. You can have single or multiple approvals, change the Approval model without changing the payload entity, and have a better focused payload entity, unburdened by metadata.

The entities could look like this:

```
@Entity
public class Policy{

  @OneToOne
  private Creation creation;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="policy")
  private List<Approval> approvals;
  ...
}
```

Creation:

```
@Entity
public class Creation{

  @OneToOne
  private Policy policy;

  private String creator;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Date createdAt;
  ...
}
```

Approval:

```
@Entity
public class Approval {

  @ManyToOne
  private Policy policy;

  private String approver;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Date approvedAt;
  ..    
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I like your approach. However, I have a few remaining questions. The reason I picked the tables approach is so that when something is approved (regardless of the approval-chain), it goes into its own table. This means that the approved item (e.g., policy) goes into effect (at specified time). Other projects can read from the approved table and act accordingly. How would someone distinguish a pending-approval from an approved?